# Error: Cannot find symbol (Coordinates)

Tags: java

Here's the new coding that I re-did:

ThreeDPoint.java

```
public class ThreeDPoint{

private double x, y, z;

public threeDPoint(){
    coordX=0;
    coordY=0;
    coordZ=0;
}

public threeDPoint(double x, double y, double z){
    coordX = x;
    coordY = y;
    coordZ = z;
}

public double getCoord(double x, double y, double z){
    return coordX;
    return coordY;
    return coordZ;
}
```

}

Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main{

```
      double coordX, coordY, coordZ;

public static void main(String[] args){

    threeDPoint myThreeDPoint=new threeDPoint();

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String coordX, coordY, coordZ;

    System.out.println("Input Coordinate X");
    myThreeDPoint.coordX(sc.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("Input Coordinate Y");
    myThreeDPoint.coordY(sc.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("Input Coordinate Z");
    myThreeDPoint.coordZ(sc.nextDouble());


}
```

}

It gave me these errors:
Build Output:
**C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        threeDPoint myThreeDPoint=new threeDPoint();
        ^
  symbol:   class threeDPoint
  location: class Main
C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        threeDPoint myThreeDPoint=new threeDPoint();
                                     ^
  symbol:   class threeDPoint
  location: class Main
2 errors**

General Output:
**Error: Could not find or load main class Main**

What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks so very much for the codes Gagandeep. Somehow I tried them but it gave out more errors than what I had before.

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:5: error: invalid method declaration; return type required

```
public threeDPoint(){
       ^
```

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:11: error: invalid method declaration; return type required

```
public threeDPoint(double x, double y, double z){
       ^
```

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol

```
myTreeDPoint.coordX(sc.nextLine());
^
```

symbol:   variable myTreeDPoint
  location: class Main

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol

```
myTreeDPoint.coordY(sc.nextLine());
^
```

symbol:   variable myTreeDPoint
  location: class Main

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol

```
myTreeDPoint.coordZ(sc.nextLine());
^
```

symbol:   variable myTreeDPoint
  location: class Main

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:22: error: non-static variable coordY cannot be referenced from a static context

```
myThreeDPoint.setCoord(coordX, coordY, coordZ);
                               ^
```

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:22: error: non-static variable coordZ cannot be referenced from a static context

```
myThreeDPoint.setCoord(coordX, coordY, coordZ);
                                       ^
```

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\Main.java:22: error: method setCoord in class ThreeDPoint cannot be applied to given types;

```
myThreeDPoint.setCoord(coordX, coordY, coordZ);
             ^
```

required: double,double,double
  found: String,double,double
  reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to double by method invocation conversion

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:6: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordX=0;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordX
  location: class ThreeDPoint

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:7: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordY=0;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordY
  location: class ThreeDPoint

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:8: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordZ=0;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordZ
  location: class ThreeDPoint

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:12: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordX = x;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordX
  location: class ThreeDPoint

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordY = y;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordY
  location: class ThreeDPoint

C:\Users\BurneySoo\Documents\ThreeDPoint.java:14: error: cannot find symbol

```
    coordZ = z;
    ^
```

symbol:   variable coordZ
  location: class ThreeDPoint

14 errors

And It still won't prompt me to input coordinate X in the general output.
it only gave me:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Main**

Comment: Are you trying to set  coordX to the value you get in the main?

Comment: Please do learn Java Naming Conventions, Class name must be in Pascal Case, i.e. First Letter Capitalized and every subsequent word starts with a capitalized alphabet, and variable names should be in Camel Case, i.e. first letter in small case and every first alphabet of a subsequent word is capitalized :-)

Comment: Lucas: Yes. The Main.java is going to be where I'll be inputting the coordinates.

Comment: @burneyjsoo : See my latest edit, hopefully that will help you in this :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not calling a constructor, you're trying to call a method.

Make a constructor for your threeDPoint class, and then use a setter to set the field coordX. You can't call

```
threeDPoint myThreeDPoint=new coordX();
```

Because this is a method, not a constructor. What you want is in your threeDPoint class a constructor like so:

```
    public threeDPoint(args){
//dostuff
}
```

and then a setter to set your Coords like

```
public void setCoordx(double coordx){
this.coordx = coordx}
```

Also, as a matter of Data hiding, make sure to delcare your fields as private or protected.

```
protected double coordX;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
threeDPoint myThreeDPoint=new threeDPoint("Send Arguments Here");
```

inside your main method, to make an object, now using this object you have to access your method `myThreeDPoint.coordX(11.11);`

Change your `ThreeDPoint` class to this :

```
public class ThreeDPoint
{
    private double x, y, z;

    public ThreeDPoint()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.z = 0;
    }

    public ThreeDPoint(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double getCoordX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public double getCoordY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }

    public double getCoordZ()
    {
        return this.z;
    }
}
```

Now make objects of this class as

```
ThreeDPoint myThreeDPoint = new ThreeDPoint();
```

So your Main Class will look like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    double coordX, coordY, coordZ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreeDPoint myThreeDPoint = new ThreeDPoint();

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String coordX, coordY, coordZ;

        System.out.println("Input Coordinate X");
        coordX = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input Coordinate Y");
        coordY = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input Coordinate Z");
        coordZ = sc.nextDouble();

        // This will initialize your Constructor with Arguments.
        ThreeDPoint myThreeDPointArgConst = new ThreeDPoint(coordX, coordY, coordZ);

        coordX = myThreeDPointArgConst.getCoordX();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate X is : " + coordX);

        coordY = myThreeDPointArgConst.getCoordY();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate Y is : " + coordY);

        coordZ = myThreeDPointArgConst.getCoordZ();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate Z is : " + coordZ);        

        // This will initialize the no-arg constructor.
        ThreeDPoint myThreeDPoint = new ThreeDPoint();

        coordX = myThreeDPoint.getCoordX();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate X is : " + coordX);

        coordY = myThreeDPoint.getCoordY();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate Y is : " + coordY);

        coordZ = myThreeDPoint.getCoordZ();
        System.out.println("Co-ordinate Z is : " + coordZ);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my latest coding above, below the old coding. I still have errors, and it won't let me input coordinate x anymore. instead, it game me errors instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the names of your class `ThreeDPoint` you changed it to the `Pascal Case` but you forgot to rename your `constructors`, they are like `threeDPoint`, hence they not referring to a constructor, hence write them as `public ThreeDPoint(){
    coordX=0;
    coordY=0;
    coordZ=0;
}`